# Filling the matrix with particular numbers chosen with certain probability

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, statistics, data-analysis

I would like to create the matrix in Python, that is dimension of w x k, where w and k are paramteres. The matrix must be such that it is filled only with the numbers {1,...,4} with probability that we can also provide as parameter, for example p_1 = (probability that we chose"1"=1/3,..., probability that we chose"4"=1/5). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `numpy.random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4], size=(w, k), p=[p1, p2, p3, p4])`

please check out the [docs](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for generating a number with defined probability
 import numpy as np

```
p1 = 0.25
p2 = 0.33
p3 = 0.25
p4 = 0.25

a = np.random.uniform()

p1 = float(input()) #get value of p1
print(a)

if a<=p1:
  print(1)
elif a<=p1+p2:
  print(2)
elif a<=p1+p2+p3:
  print(3)
elif a<=p1+p2+p3+p4:
  print(4)
```